# ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: php, .htaccess, pdo, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5.1. I uploaded my project on a shared host. Everything was going well but one day when i try to browse the site a warning message appeared

```
Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/zamzamtransport/public_html/root/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php on line 45
```

and

```
Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/zamzamtransport/public_html/root/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php on line 47
```

I googled for the solution everybody suggest me to upload my own `php.ini`.
So, I did the following:

1. Create a new `php.ini` file in root directory.
2. Edit the file and write `disable_functions=`.
3. Edit my `.htaccess` and append this line `suPHP_ConfigPath /home/zamzamtransport/public_html/`

After doing this I have another error message

```
Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/zamzamtransport/public_html/root/config/database.php on line 16
```

I realize that the hosting provider can solve it by configuring their server, I just need to contact with them.

But, I want to know is there any way to solve it from my side?

Comment: You probably need a full php.ini will all settings including extensions such as PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing now appears to be related to no PDO extension existing on the host. You will not be able to fix this with ini_set so you need to speak to your ISP (or perhaps change ISP).

Comment: Can I enable the ini_set()?